# What functions stem from Fourier Series with rational-only coefficients?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, approximation, rational-numbers

Given the Fourier series

$$f(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_k e^{ikz}$$

but with $c_k\in(\mathbb Q+ i\mathbb Q)$ instead of $\mathbb C$ (or even purely real), are the functions obtained this way in something special?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is uncountable.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Aw, silly me, thanks, I fixed that. Not that it's essential to the question...

Comment: What do you mean by special? Like if they have different properties / or are you looking for applications where such series appear? We can always find a sequence of such functions that converge to any normal Fourier series so in that sense they are almost the same as the normal class. Also many of the standard well-known Fourier series we usually work with do have (up to a possible irrational prefactor) rational coefficients.

Comment: @Winther Hm, it sounded like an interesting idea last evening, but basically your comment could be posted as accepted answer...